# How to insert a value in to the value property of a newly added input field?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to take the value of a jquery variable and add it to the value property of an input field. I thought you can use jquery variables with HTML by doing "+VARIABLE+"...but its not working. The variable name just appears and not the value.

Here is the jQuery :

```
var content_unique_id = $(this).closest('.content_unique_id').val();
    $('<input type="hidden" name="content_unique_id[]" value="+content_unique_id+" />').insertAfter('.content_container:last');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to break out of the string so the value is interpolated:

```
$('<input type="hidden" name="content_unique_id[]" value="'
    + content_unique_id + '" />')
```

Alternatively you could use `$("<input...>").val(content_unique_id)`

Answer (score 2):

`value="' + content_unique_id + '"` add single quotes before and after `+` plus signs

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of doing it:

```
$('<input>', {
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'content_unique_id[]',
    value: content_unique_id
}).insertAfter('.content_container:last');
```